# reCAPTCHA - textarea g-recaptcha-response doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I have the following problem with a page that worked reCAPTCHA v2 and no longer works

For some reason, the $ _POST ['g-recaptcha-response'] arrives empty to the file that validates the data after doing submit in the form

In the user panel of [www.google.com/recaptcha/](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/) the web is correctly added, and the keys are verified to be correct.
The point is that when you check the I am not a robot check, the text area g-recaptcha-response should be updated with the code that comes from google, but this code remains blank.

```
    <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" 
style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; 
resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
```

And this I think is the reason why it arrives empty

the code of my form is

```
            <form action="votaciones.php" method="post"  class="form" role="form" id="login">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="user" class="form-label"><?= _("Usuario") ?> : </label>

                          <input type="text" id="user"   name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="<?= _("Usuario") ?> " required autofocus/>

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="user" class="form-label"><?= _("Password") ?> : </label>

                          <input type="password" id="pass"  name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="<?= _("Password") ?> " required />

                  </div>

               
                      <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo "$reCAPTCHA_site_key"; ?>"></div>
                      </div>

                  

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="text-center">

                          <button class="btn btn-start-order" type="submit"><?= _("Acceder") ?> </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </form>   

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'  ></script>
```

and one of the PHP to which the data arrives is

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {


    // Google reCAPTCHA API secret key
    $secretKey = $reCAPTCHA_secret_key;

    // Verify the reCAPTCHA response
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    // Decode json data
    $responseKeys = json_decode($verifyResponse, true);

    // should return JSON with success as true
    if ($responseKeys["success"]) {

        //Captcha correcto
        $validoCaptcha = true;
    } else {
        // eres un robot, asi que terminamos
        $validoCaptcha = false;
         Header("Location: $url_vot/index.php?error_login=10");
         exit;
    }
  }else{
    echo "no llego" .$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    
  }
}
```

Obviously, it prints"no llego" and it does not show the post because it is empty

I have looked at other similar questions and tried the solutions but they do not solve the problem for me

For layout, I am using bootstrap, although I don't think it influences

Can anybody help me? please
I'm stuck for days and I don't understand why it doesn't update that textarea

Comment: Did u exceed the free quota of recapcha per month ? Just want to double confirm

Comment: There is no fee per month in reCAPTCHA